# WCF service httpcfg issue

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-endpoint, httpcfg.exe

We currently have a situation where we have a WCF service which generates custom excel reports for clients. This service is hosted in a windows service and uses net.tcp bindings.

We have redeveloped this service to add a http binding so ASP.NET clients can utalise some of the basic functionality without authentication.

This works fine in our development environment, but when we deploy to UAT, the service cannot open a http port and define the MEX endpoint. We have limited access to UAT, and as this was a pre-existing service before we took over the project, we are not sure what the issue is.

I know that we can run httpcfg on the server and define the endpoint passing the SID of the functional account. But is there anyway we can list what endpoints have been defined on the system? If we could list these, we could compaire our UAT and DEV environments to make sure there isnt an inconsistancy in the endpoints which have been defined. If this is the case, it would save us having to figure out if the issue lies with the group policy on the UAT system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use the netsh command.

"netsh http show urlacl" should give you a nice overview to see what is allowed for who on which http port.

Hope this helps,